# Add checking in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have class User in my project and have model UserRow (for showing user in view)
it's UserRow

```
using System;

namespace Argussite.SupplierServices.ViewModels
{
public class UserRow
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }

    public Guid SupplierId { get; set; }
    public bool ActionsAllowed { get; set; }
    public bool MailResendRequired { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and I need to add in my controller checking if ActionsAllowed

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Unlock(Guid id)
    {
        var user = Context.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return Json(CommandResult.Failure("User was not found. Please, refresh the grid and try again."));
        }

        var checkActionsAllowed = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
                                         .Select(e => new UserRow
                                             {
                                                 Id = e.Id,
                                                 ActionsAllowed = e.ActionsAllowed
                                             };
        if (checkActionsAllowed == true)
        {
            user.Status = UserStatus.Active;
            return Json(CommandResult.Success(string.Format("User {0} has been unlocked.", user.FullName)));
        }
        else return;
    }
```

but I got error with `ActionsAllowed = e.ActionsAllowed` and
in `else return;`
Help me please to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

```
Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(e => new UserRow
    {
         ActionsAllowed = e.ActionsAllowed
    };
```

returns a list of objects, not a single object.
You have queried the user above, so i guess you can write simply:

```
if (user.ActionsAllowed) {
    user.Status = UserStatus.Active;
    return Json(CommandResult.Success...);
}
```

The second problem is the `return;` statement.
Your method returns an action result, so you have to return something.
For example

```
return Json(CommandResult.Failure(
     "ActionsAllowed = false"));
```

Comment: I can't use `if (user.ActionsAllowed)` because I have property `ActionsAllowed` in `UserRow` class, but don't have it in `User`. I need to get it using user's id, but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: And where are your userRows you want to query from? You query Context.Users and i guess that are of type User, right? Then you wrote `e.ActionsAllowed`, so that comes from the User class.

Comment: I don't know how to get property ActionsAllowed from UserRow with User's id!

Comment: But who should know if not you? I don't know your app, your business rules or your data model...

Answer (score 0):

First error sounds like you `User` class doesn't provide a `ActionsAllowed` Boolean property, while the second error happens because you need to return **something** from the method that can be interpreted as an `ActionResult`.

**EDIT:**

Hmm, I didn't notice this the first time, but this:

```
var checkActionsAllowed = Context.Users.AsNoTracking()
                                 .Select(e => new UserRow
                                     {
                                         Id = e.Id,
                                         ActionsAllowed = e.ActionsAllowed
                                     };
```

followed by this:

```
if (checkActionsAllowed == true)
```

makes no sense - you're not returning a boolean result from a `Select` method, but rather an `IEnumerable`. Perhaps you should add your `User` schema to your question so that it's more obvious what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I have property `ActionsAllowed` in `UserRow` but don't have it in `User`, but I don't know how to make checking in controller using users id. And in `else` case I should get nothing.

Comment: You can't just return out of an action method - some sort of response must be sent. A simple `return false` probably works, though I would either come up with a more meaningful response code, or throw an `HttpException`. Remember, you're responding to an HTTP request.